# Improve throughput writing a lot of small files in C

Tags: c, linux, io, filesystems

I want to improve the throughput of a software that writes, several usually small, files into a network attached volume.

The volume is limited to 100 IOPS and 80 MB/s of bandwidth.

At the moment I saturate the 100 IOPS but the bandwidth is very very far from the 80 MB/s reachable, ~4 MB/s but even less.

I believe that the main issue is that we make a lot of small requests, those small requests saturated the IOPS but the bandwidth is pretty much left unexploited.

The software is written in C and I control pretty much everything down to the actual `write` syscall.

At the moment the architecture is multithreading, with several threads working as "spoolers" and making synchronous `write` call, each for a different file.

So suppose we have file `a`, `b` and `c` and thread `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.

`t1` will open `a` and call in a loop something like `write(fd_a, buff_a, 1024)` and the same will do `t2` (`write(fd_b, buff_b, 1024)`) and `t3` (`write(fd_c, buff_c, 1024)`).

Each file is a new file, so it get created at the first write.

I believe that the problem is that the requests the OS is making (after the Linux IO scheduler merge) are pretty small, in the order of 10/20 blocks (5/10 kilobyte) each.

The only way I see to fix the issue is to make bigger requests, but each file is small so I am not quite sure what is the best way forward.

A possible idea could be to make a single `write` request instead of a loop of several request, so lookup how big is the file, allocate enough memory, populate the buffer and finally execute a single `write`.

Another idea could be to switch so async io, but I don't have understand what the advantages would be in this case.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: If this is a hard drive (seems like a slow hard drive with your very low specifications) you are at the limit of the hardware. Small requests have a seek time between operations. This will limit your bandwidth. 4MB/s is actually a good result for this type of work load.

Comment: Are these small files related to each other?  Would it make sense to combine their contents into a fewer larger files files, possibly in a tar-like format?

Comment: This may seem redundant, but I suppose nothing else is done in the loop?

Comment: @drescherjm, yeah we run on very commodity hardware, 4MB/s is the upper bound the actual architecture reach, usually it is slower.

Comment: @dbush, no the files need to be written as they are now, I cannot combine them or have a different pattern...

Comment: Do you really need to write all the data? I've worked on too many jobs where the customer has wanted all the data all the time only to find that they quickly get buried in the data and can't make any sense of it.

Comment: @FlorisSA the loop is this one: https://github.com/cvmfs/cvmfs/blob/0f11e99ee72512f93a1481da22e8aae7739d2fb7/cvmfs/compression.cc#L31 the write part is done on a fast local hard drive and I don't believe is impact the performance at all. The slow drive is saturated.

Actually I am invoking the function below: https://github.com/cvmfs/cvmfs/blob/0f11e99ee72512f93a1481da22e8aae7739d2fb7/cvmfs/compression.cc#L62

Comment: @user4581301 It is a kind of database, so yes, I need to store every single one of those files.

Comment: Is it possible for you to first accumulate data into the buffer first (read from the source file) and then after some time write it in the destination file such that the no. of write calls are reduced?

Comment: You pretty much have two choices:  buy/build faster storage systems, or change your storage scheme to use fewer but larger files.  The file creation itself likely takes 2-3 IO operations.

Comment: Have you benchmarked? I had a similar problem too, and it turned out that the fwrite implementation from glibc was actually the one with the highest throughput. The other solution I tried was using write directly with various buffer sizes managed by me.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, unfortunately neither are possible, I thought the same but I just cannot.

Comment: @Siscia What can't you do?  Change the code?  Or get a faster storage system?  If you need better throughput, you **have** to do at least one of those.  Because your current design takes too many IO operations to write small amounts of data. Your current design is probably taking 4-5 IO operations to write a handful of kilobytes. A well-designed fast storage system can move 1 **megabyte** or more with each IO operation.  You're asking, "How can I turn my [Yugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zastava_Koral) into a race car and win a F1 race?"  The answer is you can't.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, is that 1 MB / IOP figure applicable to *network attached* storage such as the OP is using?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not the ones I worked on - they were FC SAN storage.  The ones I worked on were moving gigabytes/sec.  Sustained.  For weeks or months at a time.  The point is the OP has to up the number of bytes moved per IO operation, and the currently-described design is the limiting factor.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I cannot use larger files, if I need to store a small file, I need to store a small file. Also I cannot get faster disk, this **has to** run on slow disks.

If I could do any of those two thing I wouldn't be here asking... I have never said that is something easy or even possible, I am just here to get some feedback or possible ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the files into a tar-archive in memory. Then you can write the tar archive as a large request and then unzip the tar archive as a separate process which frees up the writing program.

Here is an idea that is a bit more "creative". First put the files into groups based on where they are being saved (possibly by directory). Then find the largest file in the group. Pad content of each other file so that each file is the same size. Then append the files to each other so now you have one large file. Send that write request. So now we have one large file written that contains a lot of equally sized smaller files. So use the linux split command to split the file into the multiple original files (https://kb.iu.edu/d/afar). This could work but you have to be ok with having padding at the end of files.

EDIT: It is important to note that these solutions are not scalable. The long term solution would be what @AndrewHenle suggested in the comments.